# Java iReport JDBC connection error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to create an `iReport` using netbeans iReport plugins.

When I Try to test a connection, it gives an error message as,

> SQL problems: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database
>   'st2_payroll/username:root/password:null'
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/st2_payroll/username:root/password:null

Im using **XAMPP phpmyadmin** for the data base.

the JDBC driver is MySQL `(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)`

database url is `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/st2_payroll/username:root/password:null`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, when you create a DB connection using iReport, after having selected your driver, you must enter your JDBC Url **without username and password**.

i.e. jdbc:mysql://localhost/*database_instance_name*

username and password should be added in the following text box

FF